# GPS code returning last location

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps

All I wanted to do is to get the current location using GPS before I move to next activity. So I disabled the buttons that takes me to next activities. The buttons are enabled only after getting a location using the GPS. The following code runs perfectly. But I found one bug..

Last time I used the app it was quite right. Then I moved to my University. There I launched the app and then moved to next activity as location was retrieved by then. I got  the location of my home which is about 10 kilometers away. Then after closing the application, I launched it once again and this time it retrieved the correct location.

Well, this is happening because of the line below:

```
        location = locationManagerAsync.getLastKnownLocation(providerAsync);
```

My app is retrieving the last location and enabling the buttons. But it is able to keep the current location to use for the next time I launch the app. As a result, on the second attempt, the location is retrieved perfectly.

I used a code from a question on stackoverflow.com which is given below.

```
private class MyLocationTracker extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements LocationListener {

    private Context ContextAsync;
    public MyLocationTracker (Context context){
        this.ContextAsync = context;
    }

    Dialog progress;
    private String providerAsync;
    private LocationManager locationManagerAsync;  
    double latAsync=0.0;
    double lonAsync=0.0;
    Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ContextAsync, "Loading location", "Please wait...");
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationManagerAsync = (LocationManager) ContextAsync.getSystemService(ContextAsync.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
        providerAsync = locationManagerAsync.getBestProvider(criteria, false);


        if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            providerAsync = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        } else if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            providerAsync = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        } else if (locationManagerAsync.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER)) {
            providerAsync = LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER;
            //Toast.makeText(ContextAsync, "Switch On Data Connection!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }    

        location = locationManagerAsync.getLastKnownLocation(providerAsync);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            //  System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            latAsync = location.getLatitude();
            lonAsync = location.getLongitude();

        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(ContextAsync, " Location not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {  

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
        onLocationChanged(location);
        Log.v("latAsync_lonAsync",latAsync+"_"+lonAsync);

        myCurrentLatitude = latAsync;
        myCurrentLongitude = lonAsync;

        // the buttons that were disabled in the onCreate() method  
        police.setEnabled(true);
        medical.setEnabled(true);
         fireService.setEnabled(true);
        cityCorporation.setEnabled(true);
        telePhnCall.setEnabled(true);
        getRoute.setEnabled(true);          

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationManagerAsync.requestLocationUpdates(providerAsync, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

And this is the line that I am using to call the AsyncTask from the Oncreate() method..

```
    new MyLocationTracker(TypeOfEmergency.this).execute();
```

Now the problem is, I do not want the last location to be retrieved and stored in the variables. I tried the code after removing the line

```
    location = locationManagerAsync.getLastKnownLocation(providerAsync);
```

But the app crashes in that case. Need a quick fix.

Here is the error log :: (Please have a look to the comments before having a look to the error log)

[image]

Comment: "the app crashes" -> LogCat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code something is basically wrong: the single line of code in `onLocationChanged`

```
locationManagerAsync.requestLocationUpdates(providerAsync, 0, 0, this);
```

needs to be called at the end of `doInBackground` (which does not need to be done in background). This line of code requests location updates from the provider (e.g. the GPS provider). When a new location is avaiable the `onLocationChanged` of your location listener is called (which is `MyLocationTracker` in your example due to the `this` in the line above. in `onLocationChanged` you need to react to a new location by enabling or disabling the functionality, you mentioned in your question.

The call to `getLastKnownLocation` does exectly what the name suggests: It returns the last known position, which may be quite old.

Comment: I tried calling the onLocationChanged(Location location) method just before the return statement of the doInBackground(),
But the same crashing problem persists. Let me know if I am doing something wrong..

Comment: You dont need to call onLocation. You need to call requestLocationUpdates (but not from onLocation). onLocation is automatically called whenever a new loaction is available and you need to insert the code to react to the new location there.

Comment: I did the following things: 


1. Put the following lines inside onLocationCanged() - 
            latAsync = location.getLatitude();
            lonAsync = location.getLongitude();


2.          location = locationManagerAsync.getLastKnownLocation(providerAsync);
         
         // Initialize the location fields
         if (location != null) {locationManagerAsync.requestLocationUpdates(providerAsync, 0, 0, this);



But the app is still getting crashed as soon as the activity is launched and I call the Asynctask from the OnCreate() method..

Comment: I'm not sure, how your code outside onLocationChanged() looks like. Make sure to delete all calls to onLocationChanged() in your code. E.g. the call in onPostExecute().

Comment: Actually the problem was not with the code at all!!! I was using my laptops wifi connection for the phone to send HTTP requests over wireless LAN to  localhost. As a a result the phone was actually returning the location returned by the laptop wifi! Thanks for the answer though. It did solve some issues.